# How can I upload files on ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I'm developing a multilanguaged comics website and all the inserted comics must be in english and portuguese.

I've got success on managing multiple titles doing so:

**ComicViewModel.cs:**

```
public class ComicViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A data não pode ficar em branco.")]
    [DisplayName("Data")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public IList<LocalizedTextViewModel> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

**LocalizedTextViewModel.cs:**

```
public class LocalizedTextViewModel
{
    public CultureViewModel Culture { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo não pode ficar em branco.")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**CultureViewModel.cs:**

```
public class CultureViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CultureViewModel() { }

    public CultureViewModel(Database.Culture culture)
    {
        Id = culture.Id;
        Abbreviation = culture.Abbreviation;
        Name = culture.Name;
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to manage the comic images upload. I need upload more than one image, each one referenced to it's language.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I saw [here](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/01/uploading-files-using-aspnet-mvc-2.html) a way to handle uploaded files. But using an `IEnnumerable` I can't know in which language is each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for uploading multiple files:

The Html:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{%><br />
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" size="25" />

    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" size="25" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />      
<% } %>
```

The Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads")
                    , Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Update : Getting some information about the uploaded file**

The following example shows how you can get the name/type/size/extension of a submitted HttpPostedFileBase file.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

string type = file.ContentType;

string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();

float sizeInKB = ((float)file.ContentLength) / 1024;
```

suppose that you uploaded the file `somePicture.jpeg` the output will be.

```
filename  > somePicture.jpeg
type      > image/jpeg
extension > jpeg
sizeInKB  > // the file size.
```

Comment: Ok it gets the images, but I need to know in which culture is each image. How can I reconize that? Can I change the name attribute on the form?

Comment: @Rodrigo Waltenberg: I hope my update has the answer to your first question and About the name attribute you can change it to whatever u want.

Comment: Your answer solves my question. But I think I didn't express myself well... I need it inside a ViewModel so doing this way doesn't work for me. I'll mark this question as solved and rebuild my question in another thread. thanks anyway